# Adding a spring boot project into local maven repository

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have created a gradle project ie **MicroTwo** which has a child module known as **transferObject**

settings.gradle for the parent module

```
    rootProject.name = 'microtwo'
     include 'transferObjects'
```

build.gradle for MicroTwo

```
    plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group='com.micro'
version = '1.0.4'
sourceCompatibility = '11'


repositories {

    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':transferObjects')
}
```

build.gradle for child module ie transferObject is

```
    plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.micro'
```

I want to add the child module ie **transferObject** as a jar in my local maven repository so that I can use it as a external jar in another spring boot project

Answer (score 1):

From the gradle documentation [gradlepublish](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_setup.html#publishing_overview)

We need to add a maven-publish plugin like

```
plugins {

          id 'maven-publish'
         id 'java-library'

          }
```

and define a publishing block

```
group 'com.test'
version '1.0.5'

        publishing {
                    publications {
                 myLibrary(MavenPublication) {
                      from components.java
                        }
                    }
```

The  plugin block and publish block should be added in the build.gradle of the module for which you want to create a jar. Adding the plugin maven-publish will create tasks like

```
publishPubNamePublicationToMavenLocal
```

or

```
publishPubNamePublicationToRepoNameRepository
```

running **publishPubNamePublicationToMavenLocal** will create the jar in your local m2 repository in my case I got a jar **transferObjects-1.0.5** inside `com\test\transferObjects\1.0.5` folder